# how to show group parent as one cell (by combining first columns of children rows)

Tags: javascript, css, ag-grid, ag-grid-react, ag-charts-react

I would love to manage to see the parent cell as one united cell as i showed on the screenshot below. I couldn't find solution from themeing, customization docs. Could you please tell me what is the proper way of achieving this? Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can you show us the generated HTML and CSS, not as images but as code within the question.

Comment: @AHaworth here is a sandbox i was working on. could you please try to make groups look like as I showed in picture above? Thanks https://codesandbox.io/s/ag-grid-packages-forked-84h236?file=/src/index.js

Comment: Please put the generated HTML and CSS into your question - external sites will become useless in future as they are removed or mended thus rendering your question of no use to future readers. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are

https://plnkr.co/edit/oOtlvoTPuaIDB2Kd?preview

**This is the closest solution I can achieve**

Basically, we use rowSpan feature. In this example, we have 2 groups; country and year respectively. To get the desired result, we add a rowSpan method like that

```
rowSpan: (params) => {
  // when all group columns collapsed
  if (params.node.field === 'country') {
    return 1;
  // when first level is expanded
  } else if (params.node.field === 'year') {
    return (
      params.node.parent.childrenAfterGroup.length -
      params.node.childIndex
    );
  // when second level is expanded
  } else {
    // if it is the latest group, our calculation logic changes
    if (params.node.parent.lastChild) {
      return (
        params.node.parent.childrenAfterGroup.length -
        params.node.childIndex
      );
    } else
      return (
        params.node.parent.childrenAfterGroup.length -
        1 +
        params.node.parent.parent.childrenAfterGroup.length -
        params.node.childIndex -
        params.node.parent.childIndex
      );
    }
  }
},
```

The idea is to count rows regarding the row child index. You need to observe the code and understand it, it's somewhat complicated.

**Result**

[image: Result]

**UPDATE**

If you want to have a background color only if the country column is expanded, we should add another condition to check it this way

```
if (params.node.parent.expanded)
```

Here's the updated plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/oOtlvoTPuaIDB2Kd?preview

Comment: Could you please add "rag-green" class only when a country is expanded? if it is collapsed it should not have green background.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Try to expand Australia.

Comment: thank you very much :)) I really appreciate it. iyi gunler

Comment: İyi günler size de, teşekkürler ;)